# A list of 100 statements

Tags: logical-deduction, paradox

I was working my way through some puzzles in [Discrete Maths by Rosen](http://www.flipkart.com/discrete-mathematics-its-applications-combinatorics-graph-theory-english-7th/p/itmdwxxszhczjrnf), when I came across the following question:

> The $n^{th}$ statement in a list of 100 statements is : *"Exactly $n$ of the statements in this list are false"*
>
> - What conclusion can you draw from these statements ?
> - Answer the first part if the $n^{th}$ statement is : *"At least $n$ of the statements in this list are false" ?*
> - Answer the second part assuming that the list contains 99 statements ?

***My Solution (Inadequate):***

> - The 99th Statement is True and the rest are false
> - I am all thumbs for the next two parts

***Book solution:***

> - The 99th Statement is True and the rest are false
> - Statements 1 through 50 are all true and statements 51 through 100 are
>     all false
> - This cannot happen; it is a paradox, showing that these cannot be statements.

***My question:***

Why is this so?

Comment: It seems that you are looking for a mathematical proof. If that is the case, this question should be moved to [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Actually , @dmg - this is given in the section of puzzles and not mathematical proofs ;)

Comment: You ask "why is this so?". The only proper way to explain it is through proving it. I would suggest that you try proving it by contradiction. Assume `n < 99` and `n = 100` for the first example and you will find your contradictions :)

Comment: @pranav What have you tried? (In true math.SE style, I think you'd learn more if we led you through the process than if we fed you the answer.)

Answer (score 6):

For the second part, "*At least $n$ of the statements in this list are false*," you have some number $k$ of false statements, and $100-k$ true statements. It should be clear that the $n^{th}$ statement is true whenever $n\le k$, and false otherwise, which means that there also $k$ true statements. So, you have $k=100-k$, which means that $k=50$. There are $50$ true and $50$ false statements, which means the first $50$ statements are true and the rest are false.

This method should make it clear that there is *something* wrong with the third problem, since it tells you that there should be $49.5$ true statements, and how can you have a (logical) half-truth? To see the paradox, suppose that statements 1 through 49 are true, and the rest are false. Then there are $50$ false statements, so the $50^{th}$ statement is true. But the $50^{th}$ was one of the false statements. Now there are only $49$ statements that are false, so "At least $50$ of the statemnets in this list are false" is false. This gives $50$ false statements again, so we're back where we started.

An odd number of statements in a list like that produces a version of the Liar's Paradox.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer the second part assuming that the list contains 99 statements:**

Assume that exactly $x$ statements are false. Then every statement $n$ with number $n\ge x+1$ is false, and every statement $m$ with number $m\le x$ is true. There are exactly $99-x$ statements with $n\ge x+1$, and they coincide with the $x$ false statements. Therefore $x=99-x$. This is impossible, and the problem has no solution.